Which of my "user.config" files is the latest?
My application regularly writes a "user.config" file. As a result, I might have several of those file, as you can see here:
C:\Users\DDM\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Application.exe_Url_0pxm4tjihtf4gojic1ie1emq0ikpux0l\1.0.0.0\user.config
C:\Users\DDM\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Application.exe_Url_2b3b4tyfmzkmjhm51ejgkixpxa1mj5mv\1.0.0.0\user.config
C:\Users\DDM\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Application.exe_Url_35225euvnelhwk1uagjvfdpuat5ri4pq\1.0.0.0\user.config
C:\Users\DDM\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Application.exe_Url_5n2gl0ysqrdxoqfoamypqiowrjzi1urz\1.0.0.0\user.config

As those files are located inside the "AppData" directory, the Windows search does not work:

Is there any parameter or switch I can add to DIR /S in order to add the last modification date (as ls -l in UNIX)?
Thanks in advance
Edit: forfiles attempt:
In the meantime I've invented following forfiles command:
forfiles /S /M user.config /C "cmd /c echo @path ":" @fdate, @ftime"

However, this gives a lot of "Access denied" errors.
Is there a 2>/dev/null, like in UNIX?

I just found the following: 2>nul.
I checked this and it worked:
forfiles /S /M user.config /C "cmd /c echo @path ":" @fdate, @ftime" 2>nul

This gives the list of files I was looking for, without any error messages.

@Ramhound: I removed the "bad" reference and my comment, referring to it :-)


Is there any parameter or switch I can add to DIR /S in order to add the last modification date (as ls -l in UNIX)?

Cmd's built-in dir already displays that by default. You've probably hidden it using /B in your script.
Likewise PowerShell's Get-ChildItem returns objects which have a .LastWriteTime property (also displayed by default).
dir ~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Application.exe_*\1.0.0.0\user.config | select LastWriteTime, FullName


Is there a 2>/dev/null, like in UNIX?

There is but the null device is NUL or NUL:. (Technically also \\.\GLOBALROOT\Device\Null or something along those lines, but I don't think that works in Cmd.)
I think PowerShell prefers 2> $null (streams in PowerShell are weird).
